# Search/ filter function javascript does not work

Tags: javascript, html, search, filter

I would like to modify the code I saw on the W3school and the code is to generate a filter/ search function.
the original code is

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
  // Declare variables
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById('myInput');
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
  li = ul.getElementsByTagName('li');

  // Loop through all list items, and hide those who don't match the search query
  for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
    txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
    if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      li[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      li[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

The code below is meant to compare the input with the data-caption attribute of the anchor element but it does not work. Can anyone kindly point out what is wrong? Thanks so much!

```
function search() {   
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById('search-input');
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  ul = document.getElementById('search-opt');
  li = ul.getElementsByTagName('li');
  for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0].getAttribute('data-caption');
    txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
    if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      li[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      li[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Ahoj, while I think I can see the problem and help you out, this question is not very helpful for anyone else. I'd suggest a bit more analysis on your side and more specific question, rather than "this chunk of code doesn't work". Break it down into steps, make some debug printouts of the variables involved and try to figure out which part of the code is failing your expectation :) your rubber duck

Comment: Sorry that maybe I did not state clearly and actually I know what is wrong with my code(the getAttribute('data-caption')) but I don't know how to fix it. I understand your intention of not just giving out the answer, or could you please give me some hint how to fix it?

Comment: `a` was what? an "a" element. Now it is an attribute. The rubber duck would like to point out that elements do not behave like attributes, they don't have the same properties.

Comment: Thanks! your hint does help!

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `.getAttribute('data-caption')`, maybe it helps because W3Schools doesn't use it in their code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I wanted the search function to compare the input with the data-caption of anchor elements and that's why I added the getAttribute method.  May I know why such addition cause the function to stop running?